# python 2.3 regex problem

Tags: python, regex

how do i set the regular expressions flags like multiline and ignorecase in python 2.3?

in python 2.6 its like this

`re.findall(pattern,string, re.multiline | re.ignorecase)`

but this doesn't seem to wok for python 2.3, any ideas?

pointers appreciated

edit: sorry, it was python 2.3 not 2.4

Comment: re.multiline doesn't work on 2.6 or any other version-- there's no such attribute. The names of those flags (like all module-level constants) are in UPPERCASE in all Python versions. When asking a question, show the code that you actually ran, and don't type it from memory, use copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile the regexp in advance with [`re.compile(pattern[, flags])`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile). Then you can pass the options as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

the flags are uppercase in 2.4, e.g.:

```
re.findall(pattern,string, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

works for me;

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep  3 2009, 15:37:37) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("Test","Test\ntest\nTEST",re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)
['Test', 'test', 'TEST']
```